# Picture inside a row wrap container overflows just a little

Tags: html, css, figure

All of that container's items `article` wrap the way they should but the right border of that `image` overflows the container's `article` border.

My workaround is to add a `mediaquery @1041px` and a little `padding` so the border never reaches the image's border but there must be a cleaner way to figure that out.

And w/ or w/o the `figure` the result is the same.

```
article {
      border: solid black;
      border-width: 6px;
      font-family: 'Lato';
      font-size: 2.5em;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-justify: distribute;
      padding: 5px;}

figure {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 0;}

img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border: black solid;
      border-width: 6px;
      margin: 5px;}
```

////

```
  <article>
  <figure>
    <img class="id" src="images/idkort_vit_2.jpg" alt="Marine Heide 
    portrait" />
  </figure>

<div class="intro">
  <div id="one">XXX XXX är född i XXX XXX och bosatt i XXX XXX. 
  </div>

  <div id="two">Hon har vuxit upp i en mångkulturell familj med XXX 
  bakgrund och är verksam som XXX, 
  XXX och XXX.
  </div>

  <div id="three">XXX XXX är doktor vid XXX XXX och har 
  också läst XXX XXX samt 
  XXX XXX på XXX XXX i XXX XXX.
  </div>
</div> 
  </article>
```

https://codepen.io/cykelcykel/pen/dyyvGBg

I don't want the container's right border to touch the image's border when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for the `img` as this will account the border added and apply `margin` for `figure` than the `img` itself.

```css
article {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 6px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-justify: distribute;
  padding: 5px;
}

figure {
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: black solid;
  border-width: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

#one {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 2;
}

#two {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 2;
}

#three {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <figure>
    <img class="id" src="https://i.postimg.cc/9X9twXdN/idkort-vit-2.jpg" alt="Marine Heide portrait" />
  </figure>
  <div class="intro">
    <div id="one">XXX XXX är född i XXX XXX och bosatt i XXX XXX.</div>
    <div id="two">Hon har vuxit upp i en mångkulturell familj med XXX bakgrund och är verksam som XXX, XXX och XXX.</div>
    <div id="three">XXX XXX är doktor vid XXX XXX och har också läst översättning samt tolkning på XXX XXX i XXX.</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the border on the figure element instead:

```css
article {
  border: 6px solid black;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 2.5em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-justify: distribute;
  padding: 5px;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: solid 6px #000;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#one, #two, #three {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 2;
}

#three {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <figure>
    <img class="id" src="https://placekitten.com/1200/400" />
  </figure>
  <div class="intro">
    <div id="one">XXX XXX är född i XXX XXX och bosatt i XXX XXX.</div>
    <div id="two">Hon har vuxit upp i en mångkulturell familj med XXX bakgrund och är verksam som XXX, XXX och XXX.</div>
    <div id="three">XXX XXX är doktor vid XXX XXX och har också läst översättning samt tolkning på XXX XXX i XXX.</div>
  </div>
</article>
```